# While loop only happens once

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

My `while` loop only happens once while I need to check multiple times to make sure the hour input as 24 hr. What is it I'm doing wrong? I know probably something, but I've been playing around with it, and I'm still getting the while loop only once.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int h=0;
    int m=0;
    int d=0;
    int ht=0;
    int t=0;

    printf("Starting Hour: ");

    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &h);
    }
    while (h > 0 && h < 24);

    printf ("Invalid input. Please use 24hr format\n");
    printf ("Starting Hour: ");
    scanf("%d",&h);

    printf("Starting Minute: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Starting Time is %d:%d, what is the duration? ", h, m);
    scanf("%d",&d);
    t=(m+d);
    ht=t/60;
    h=(h+ht)%24;
    m=t%60;

    printf("Ending Time: %d:%d",h,m);
    printf("\n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you reject `0`?

Comment: because i my hour is in 24 hr format

Comment: actually never mind you are right.

Comment: Loop only once? Not reproduced. Maybe you tried with only wrong input. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hDmNIsfbqryTIjOM

Comment: Why h < 0? so it will be negative?

Comment: `%d` reads a signed decimal -> `h` can be negative, if you enter a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `while` loop worked only once simply because the condition became false.

I guess you want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int h=0;
    int m=0;
    int d=0;
    int ht=0;
    int t=0;


    do
    {
        if (h != 0) printf ("Invalid input. Please use 24hr format\n"); /* get this inside the loop */
        printf("Starting Hour: "); /* get this inside the loop */
        if (scanf("%d", &h) != 1) return 1; /* add checking if the reading is successful */
    }
    while (h < 0 || 24 <= h); /* loop while the input is invalid */

    /* remove extra scanf and printf */

    printf("Starting Minute: ");
    if (scanf("%d",&m) != 1) return 1; /* add checking if the reading is successful */
    printf("Starting Time is %d:%d, what is the duration? ", h, m);
    if (scanf("%d",&d) != 1) return 1; /* add checking if the reading is successful */
    t=(m+d);
    ht=t/60;
    h=(h+ht)%24;
    m=t%60;

    printf("Ending Time: %d:%d",h,m);
    printf("\n");

    /* no extra reading */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: People in SO sure love to copy-paste

Comment: That my answer was identical and you said it didn't work

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep asking for input when the user gives **invalid** input you need to check:

```
while (h < 0 || h >= 24);
```

As it is right now, you are getting the `while` to execute only once because the input is **valid** and fits the pattern of `h > 0 && h < 24`.

Comment: as soon as i enter like 26, nothing happens, all blanks

Comment: Then you have to enter a **new hour** (value for `h`). That's **exactly the same** as the answer you accepted just without the `printf` etc..

Answer (score 0):

As you want an hour entered in 24h format, you have to accept numbers between 0-23 for the hour part, as it can span from 00:00 to 23:59.

So your loop expression should be rather: `while (h < 0 || h > 23);`